# facebook authetication issue using like box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm using the facebook like box in a project. The issue there is that when I'm log out and click on the like button, it open a page asking me to log in, that's fine, but if I close that  page and click again on the like button, that page it's not open again, the only way to solve the issue, it's refreshing the page.

Here is a video to show the issue http://screencast.com/t/z8fNAGDqYuS, every single time that the cursor is on the like button I'm making click on it, and it's not working.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's is not your problem to solve, it's Facebook's and why you need do that? I mean if you clicked on the like button that means you have intention of liking of that `OG URL` then why would close the login popup O.o?

Comment: Thanks, you're right that's not my problem to solve.